# ourOfMemory android-php-mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello I'm reading text file in android wich contains 30k of row 
and then each 5k of rows i put them into one string and then send them to php 
so i send them 5 by 5 so 6 variables 30/5=6
when i send 1 or 2 or 3 varables with nameValyePair it's ok but when sending them all its out of memory i tried send 3 then back and calling System.gc and then send more 2 and also outofMemory 
Please Help i want to send the 6 variables at one tme to php 
and here's my Codes

```
JsonParser Class



  package system.registrationsystem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {



    JSONObject jobj=null;
    InputStream is=null;
    static String json="";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient=null;
    HttpPost httpPost=null;


public JSONParser(){    
}
public void OpenConnection(String url){
     httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpPost=new HttpPost(url);


}

public void InsertDataIntoServer(List<NameValuePair> parm){
    StringBuilder sb=null;
    try{


        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parm));
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
    while( (line=reader.readLine()) !=null ){
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
    is.close();
    Log.v("Return if SB",sb.toString());

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("exp",e.getMessage());
    }



}

}
```

MainActivity

```
    package system.registrationsystem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//final 2
    public static String urlInsert = "http://10.0.2.2/registeration_system/insertdata2.php";

    public ProgressDialog pDialog = null,dialog=null;
    JSONParser Parser = null;

    List<String> dept,course,course_has_teacher,student,student_has_course,teacher = null;
    long totalTime,endTime, startTime;
    long totalTime2,endTime2, startTime2;

    int row=0;

    List<NameValuePair>pp=null;
    public void PrepareListsAndConnection(){

        dept = new ArrayList<String>();

        dept.add("INSERT INTO `department` VALUES ");

        course = new ArrayList<String>();
        course.add("INSERT INTO `course` VALUES ");

        student = new ArrayList<String>();
        student.add("INSERT INTO `student` VALUES ");


        teacher = new ArrayList<String>();
        teacher.add("INSERT INTO `teacher` VALUES ");

        student_has_course = new ArrayList<String>();
        student_has_course.add("INSERT INTO `student_has_course` VALUES ");

        course_has_teacher = new ArrayList<String>();
        course_has_teacher.add("INSERT INTO `course_has_teacher` VALUES ");
        Parser = new JSONParser();
        Parser.OpenConnection(urlInsert);

    }
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String>q=new ArrayList<String>();
        PrepareListsAndConnection();



        Button insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Insert().execute();

            }
        });


    }


    //AsyncTask To Insert Data
    class Insert extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMessage("Inserting Data Into Server");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                String line = null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                        .open("Data.txt"), "UTF-8"));

                List<NameValuePair> parms = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    String table = line.substring(line.indexOf("#") + 1,
                            line.indexOf("$"));
                    String linefiltered = line.substring(table.length() + 2);
                    String[] arr = linefiltered.split("\\$");


                    if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("department")) { 



                         dept.add("( " + arr[0] + ",\'" + arr[1] + "\',\'" + arr[2] + "\')" ); 
                                            row++;


                     }else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("course")) {

                             course.add("( " + arr[0] + ",\'" + arr[1] + "\',\'" + arr[2] + "\')" ); 
                                                row++;


                     } else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("teacher")) {




                         teacher.add("( " + arr[0] + ",\'" + arr[1] + "\',\'" + arr[2] + "\' " +
                                  ",\'" + arr[3] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[4] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[5] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[6] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[7] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[8] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[9] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[10] + "\'"+

                                ")" ); 
                                                    row++;

                     } else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
                         student.add("( " + arr[0] + ",\'" + arr[1] + "\',\'" + arr[2] + "\' " +
                                  ",\'" + arr[3] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[4] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[5] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[6] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[7] + "\'"+
                                  ",\'" + arr[8] + "\'"+

                                ")" ); 
                                                    row++;


                     }
                      else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("student_has_course"))
                     { 

                                 student_has_course.add("( " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + ")" ); 
                                                    row++;

                     }else if (table.equalsIgnoreCase("course_has_teacher")) {


                             course_has_teacher.add("( " + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + ")" ); 
                                                row++;

                        }else {

                     }      

                }

            long ftime=System.currentTimeMillis();

            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values1", dept.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$")));
            Log.v("Dept Length: ",dept.size()+"");
            dept.clear();
            dept=null;
            Log.v("parmDept: ",parms.size()+"");
              Runtime.getRuntime().gc();


            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values2", (course.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$")) ));
              Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

            course.clear();
            course=null;

            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values3", teacher.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$")   ));
            Log.v("parms1: ",parms.size()+"");
            teacher.clear();
            teacher=null;
              Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values4",   student.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$")));
            reader=null;
            student.clear();
            student=null;

            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values5", student_has_course.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$")  ));

            parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values6",  course_has_teacher.toString().replaceFirst(",",
                     "$").replaceFirst("\\[", "$").replaceFirst("\\]", "$") ));





              Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

             Parser.InsertDataIntoServer(parms);
            long fend=System.currentTimeMillis();



                endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

                      reader.close();




            }









            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       



            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pDialog.dismiss();
            ProgressDialog p = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            p.setCancelable(true);
            p.setTitle(row + " Inserting into DataBase's Done");
             totalTime = endTime-startTime;
            p.setMessage(row + " Row Inserted in: " + totalTime
                    + " MillSecond\n" +
                    " in Seconds: " + (totalTime / 1000));
            p.setIndeterminate(false);
            p.show();

        }

    }

}
```

PHP Code

```
    <?php

$con=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die(mysql_error());
        $db=mysql_select_db("register_0");


$values1=$_POST['values1'];
$values2=$_POST['values2'];
$values3=$_POST['values3'];
$values4=$_POST['values4'];
$values4=$_POST['values5'];
$values4=$_POST['values6'];


    mysql_query($values1) or die(mysql_error($con));

        mysql_query($values2) or die(mysql_error($con));

        mysql_query($values3) or die(mysql_error($con));

        mysql_query($values4) or die(mysql_error($con));
        mysql_query($values5) or die(mysql_error($con));
        mysql_query($values6) or die(mysql_error($con));

?>
```